# Как залить изображение с прозрачным фоном одним цветом через CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, css3

[image: первое изображение]
[image: второе изображение]
[image: третье изображение]

Есть картинка (многоцветная PNG с прозрачным фоном), которую нужно залить одним цветом со стороны браузера. Желательно сохранить мягкие края как в третьем варианте, опираясь на альфа-канал. Достаточно поддержки современными браузерами (FF ~30+/Сhrome/Safari/iOS ~7+/Android ~4+). Ищу решение через CSS, если такового нет, то через JS (+jQuery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конкретно в данном случае можно воспользоватся свойством `filter`.

Оно применяет визуальные эффекты к элементам.

Предоставляет такие эффекты как: размытие (`blur`), яркость (`brightness`), контраст (`contrast`), инверсия цветов(`invert`) и т.п.

Результат его работы будет таким:

```css
#two {
  filter: invert(50%);
  -webkit-filter: invert(50%);
}

#three {
  filter: brightness(0.0);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0.0);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0AiT.png">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0AiT.png" id="two">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0AiT.png" id="three">
```

`invert` - задается в процентах 1-100%, так и десятичных значениях 0.5.

`brightness` - задается в процетах 0%, так и в десятичных значениях 0.0.

Подробней о [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

Поддержка свойства браузерами: [filter](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)

Comment: Размытие всё же blur, а не blue, опечатались. Спасибо, решение оказалось очень простым.

Answer (score 0):

В CSS такого сделать нельзя. 
Лучше это делать на сервере. 
Можно ещё через Canvas это сделать, но вряд ли Вам подойдёт этот вариант.

Comment: Canvas подойдёт, если проще/быстрее ничего нет. Имеете в виду globalCompositeOperation source-in?